# How to split text into paragraphs?

Tags: c#

I need to split a string into paragraphs and count those paragraphs (paragraphs separated by 2 or more empty lines).
In addition I need to read each word from the text and need the ability to mention the paragraph which this word belong to.

For example (Each paragraph is more then one line and two empty lines separates between paragraphs):

```
This is
the first
paragraph


This is 
the second
paragraph


This is 
the third
paragraph
```

Comment: show the code which you have tried

Comment: And add how a paragraph would be defined... New line?

Comment: you can spliting text with someText.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: I cannot understand why such questions got 3 votes while other that do not post their code get negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
        var paragraphMarker = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        var paragraphs = fileText.Split(new[] {paragraphMarker},
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
        {
            var words = paragraph.Split(new[] {' '}, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                 .Select(w => w.Trim());
            //do something
        }
```

You may need to change line delimiter, file can have different variants like `"\n"`, `"\r"`, `"\r\n"`.

Also you can pass specific characters inside `Trim` function to remove symbols like `'.'`,`','`,`'!'`,`'"'` and others.

**Edit:** To add more flexibility you can use regexp for splitting paragraphs:

```
        var paragraphs = Regex.Split(fileText, @"(\r\n?|\n){2}")
                              .Where(p => p.Any(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
        foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
        {
            var words = paragraph.Split(new[] {' '}, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                 .Select(w => w.Trim());
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: What this line actually executing?     .Select(w => w.Trim());

Comment: @CobyAbutbul `Trim` removes white space characters from the beginning and end of string (there also `TrimStart` - only from beginning, and `TrimEnd` - only from the end). If you what to remove some other symbols, like `'.'` for example, you can pass them to 'Trim' like  `Trim(new []{'.',',','?','!'})` in this way it will remove all those chars from the beginning and end of string. `Select` function apply `Trim` to every string that we get from `Split` function.

Comment: Great. Thank  Andrey Tretyak

Comment: As i'm understanding paragraphs.Length should hold the numbers of paragraphs i have, but it's returns 1 all the time.

Comment: @CobyAbutbul May be your file has different line ending symbols. Try something like this: `var paragraphs = fileText.Split(new[] {paragraphMarker, "\n\n", "\r\r", "\r\n\r\n"},
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. You can also consider using regexp like `var paragraphs = Regex.Split(fileText, @"(\r\n?|\n){2}")`. It would be good if you can add text example with two or more paragraphs.

Comment: Something like that (2 empty lines seperates between paragraphs):

This is the
first
paragraph


This is the
second
paragraph


This is the
thired
paragraph


and so on.....

Comment: @CobyAbutbul this approach will not work if those two line separators will have some characters between them, if that is your case your should change regexp to react on characters that can be between separators.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to split the text in paragraphs, but do you have a delimiter to tell you to know you need to split the string?, for example if you want to identify the paragraph with "." this should do the trick

`string paragraphs="My first paragraph. Once upon a time";`

`string[] words = paragraphs.Split('.');`

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

The result for this will be:

```
My first paragraph
Once upon a time
```

Just remember that the "." character was removed!.

Comment: Sounds a solution like splitting into sentences not paragraphs. The OP needs to post what defines a paragraph too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<string> SplitLine(string isstr, int size = 100)
    {
        var words = isstr.Split(new[] { ' ' },
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string> lo = new List<string>();
        string tmp = "";

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((tmp.Length + words[i].Length) > size)
            {
                lo.Add(tmp);
                tmp = "";
            }
            tmp += " " + words[i];
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tmp))
        {
            lo.Add(tmp);
        }

        return lo;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.